# Simplest, Safe Method for Trimming File Paths

Tags: regex, shell, filepath

I have a script that does a lot of file-processing, and it's good enough to receive its paths using null-characters as a separator for safety.

However, it process all paths as absolute (saves some headaches), but these are a bit unwieldy for output purposes, so I'd like to remove a chunk of the path from my output. Now, plenty of options spring to mind, but the difficulty is in using these in a way that's safe for any arbitrary path that I might encounter, which is where things get a bit trickier.

Here's a quick example:

```
#!/bin/sh
TARGET="$1"
find "$TARGET" -print0 | while IFS= read -rd '' path; do
    # Process path for output here
    path_str="$path"
    echo "$path_str"
done
```

So in the above script I want to take `path` and remove `TARGET` from it, in the most compatible way possible (e.g - nothing bash specific), it needs to be able to remove *only* from the start of the string, i.e - `/foo/bar` becomes `bar`, `/foo/bar/foo` becomes `bar/foo` and `/bar/foo` remains `/bar/foo`. It should also cope with any possible characters in a file-name, including characters that some file-systems support such as tildes, colons etc., as well as pesky inverted quotation characters.

I've hacked together some messy solutions using `sed` by first escaping any characters that might break my regular expression, but this is a very messy way of doing things, so I'm hoping there are some simpler methods out there. In case there isn't, here's by solution so far:

```
SAFE_CHARS='s:\([[/.*]\):\\\1:g'
target_safe=$(printf '%s' "$TARGET" | sed "$SAFE_CHARS")
path_str=$(printf '%s' "$path" | sed "s/^$target_safe//g')
```

There's probably a few characters missing that I should be escaping in addition to those ones, and apologies for any typos.

Comment: The `-d` option to `read` is `bash`-specific (or at least, not part of the POSIX standard). If you use that, you may as well use other `bash` extensions as well.

Answer (score 1):

To remove a prefix from a string,

```
$ TARGET=/foo/
$ path=/foo/bar
$ echo "${path#$TARGET}"
bar
```

The `#` operator for parameter expansion is part of the POSIX standard and will work in any POSIX-compliant shell.

Comment: This does seem like the best method, but unfortunately I think my shell environment (on OS X) is using `ash`. It supports some bash-isms, but while it doesn't throw an error when I use this method to trim the path, it doesn't work either (just returns the full, unmodified path). Any ideas why that might be? I'd have thought it would throw an error of some kind.

Comment: Sorry, just checked and OS X does use `bash` for shell scripts, but for some reason various bash specific features aren't supported, that work just fine when used in terminal. I suppose I could just run my script(s) via `bash` rather than `sh`, very strange environment to work in!

Comment: Some `bash`-specific features are suppressed when `bash` is invoked as `sh`, but that should not be the case here. As I noted in my answer, `#` is not a `bash`ism. Could you add a specific example of a `TARGET`/`path` pair which doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple find:

```
export TARGET="$1"
find "$TARGET" -exec bash -c 'sed "s|^$TARGET\/||" <<< "$1"' - '{}' \;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I actually prefer to keep `$path` as an absolute path when working on it, I just want to trim `$TARGET` for output purposes, I'll clarify my example accordingly. Also, I'm not sure if pipe characters will work for `sed` either, as HFS for example will happily allow pipe characters in file names.